# Strange problem on matrices

Tags: matrices

Prove that for any symmetric matrix A (nxn) and any vectors $x,y \in R^{n}$ is true: $(Ax, y) = (x, Ay)$. Main problem here, is that I don't understand what to do in general. What are those brackets?

Comment: The brackets mean scalar product, and the identity comes from the fact that a symmetric matrix satisfies $A=A^T$

Comment: $(x,y)$ is the scalar product given by $(x,y)=x^Ty$.